# Не могу создать внешний ключ в бд

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-key

Помогите, пожалуйста)Вроде нет проблем, поля одинаковые, но не хочет связывать. Последовательность правильная. Сначала создаётся users после неё сразу же mems.

Ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `mems` add constraint `mems_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`user_id`))

PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")
  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/moderation/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

PDOStatement::execute()
  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/moderation/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458
```

Вот миграция users:

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('access_moderation')->nullable();
        $table->integer('access_mems')->nullable();
        $table->integer('access_admin')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
    });
```

Вот миграция mems

```
 Schema::create('mems', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('img');
        $table->integer('author_id');

        $table->foreign('author_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');

    });
```

PS. Поле user_id нужно для привязки авторизованного пользователя(вк)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/975725/256824

Comment: Не понимаю. Вроде всё хорошо

Comment: Изменил свой вопрос.

Comment: Получилось создать только на переменную BigIncrement, но мне нужно именно Integer

Comment: Нет, не работает(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По факту поля `id` и `user_id` должны быть уникальны в пределах таблицы и привычнее было бы привязываться именно к `id`.

> ... но мне нужно именно Integer

Связываемые поля должны быть проиндексированы и иметь один тип и длину. В примере ниже использован уникальный индекс для поля `user_id` в родительской таблице:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');

  // ... остальные поля.

  $table->integer('user_id')->unique();
});
```

```php
Schema::create('mems', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');

  // ... остальные поля.

  $table->integer('author_id');

  $table->foreign('author_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
});
```

Выполните в командной строке `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

***Эта команда удалит все таблицы из Базы Данных и выполнит команду `migrate`***.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Больше информации по вашей ошибке [MySQL Error Code 1215: "Cannot add foreign key constraint"](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/).